# How i pass token from java class to retrofit APIClient

Tags: android, json, parsing, retrofit, retrofit2

> I am using retrofit library for parsing data from json.But now i required to pass token in my request. I have set token in one Global class.Now i want to use that token in APIClient.But when i pass , it through null.

**This is my APIClient**

```
public class APIClient  {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://kartpays.bizs/api/v5/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static final String FOLLOW_URL ="http://kartpays.biz/api/v1/follow/";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request originalRequest = chain.request();


                Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                        .header("token", **I want to pass token here**)
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .method(originalRequest.method(), originalRequest.body())
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(FOLLOW_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**In this class i stored token**

```
 public class LibFile {
    Context context;

    public  static SharedPreferences settings;
    private static LibFile instance;
    public static LibFile getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LibFile(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public LibFile(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREFS_FILE_NAME_PARAM, 0);
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return settings.getString("user_id", "");
    }

    public void setUser_id(String link) {
        settings.edit().putString("user_id", link).commit(); //get link from here
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return settings.getString("token","");//pass key here
    }

    public static void setToken(String userName) {
        settings.edit().putString("token", userName).commit();//get key from here
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        settings.edit().clear().commit();
        settings.edit().remove("link").commit();
    }
}
```

> Please Suggest me how to pass token dynamically. I could not pass static token because it changes continuously.Thanks in advance

Comment: you can pass it where you are calling your method getRetrofitInstance("token")

Comment: If my answer is right then you can also upvote it. It would be useful for other as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your token is stored in `SharedPreference` then check out below changes of your code,

```
  public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(Context mContext) {

        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREFS_FILE_NAME_PARAM, 0);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request originalRequest = chain.request();


                Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                        .header("token", settings.getString("token", ""))
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .method(originalRequest.method(), originalRequest.body())
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(FOLLOW_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution suiting your code would be:

```
 Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                        .header("token", LibFile.getInstance(mContext).getToken())
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .method(originalRequest.method(), originalRequest.body())
                        .build();
```

Check this line: `.header("token", LibFile.getInstance(mContext).getToken())`

Which take an instance from the LibFile and gets a token.

Answer (score 0):

In your http request, the header key should be "Authorization" instead of "token".

```
Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", **I want to pass token here**)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .method(originalRequest.method(), originalRequest.body())
                    .build();
```

You can use below methods to put and get token from shared preferences.

```
public static boolean setStringPreference(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (preferences != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(key)) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        return editor.commit();
    }
    return false;
}

public static String getStringPreference(String key) {
    String value = null;
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (preferences != null) {
        value = preferences.getString(key, null);
    }
    return value;
}
```